# Installing and configuring neo4js for node.js

Tags: node.js, maven, neo4j

I am trying to use neo4j database with Express (node.js). I've been looking for an API to manage the connections and the transactions. I've found neo4js which looks very promising but I am having troubles to install it.

I have followed all the steps descrived in the github page:

```
git clone http://github.com/jakewins/neo4js.git

cd neo4js

mvn package
```

But I get all this errors:

```
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]

[ERROR]   

[ERROR]   The project org.neo4j.drivers:neo4js:0.9-SNAPSHOT (/Users/Javi/Programming/node/neo4j-neo4js-5245de1/pom.xml) has 1 error

[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find org.neo4j.build:parent-pom:pom:31 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 12, column 10 -> [Help 2]

[ERROR] 

[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR] 

[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the 
following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException

[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

Does anyone have any clue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just adjusted the parent pom, could you pull again and try, please?